# Yii - TbGridView with TbButton to show all rows in a grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, gridview, yii

I recently changed the app front end to be fully integrated with bootstrap.

Before the grid view would show x number of rows and I had a link at the top of the grid view that when clicked would show all rows in the grid, as follows:

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Display All Rows', array('policy/index', 'pageSize'=>9999, )); ?>
```

I would like to change that to an ajax enabled TbButton that when clicked would show all rows in the grid.

Any ideas of how to achieve that?

Thanks and happy Thanksgiving!!!

Answer (score 0):

So the gridview displays the number of rows based on the following code in the model:

```
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                    'criteria'=>$criteria,

     'pagination'=>array(
         'pageSize'=>10),
      )
    );
```

Now the question is how to change the number of rows displayed when clicking the button (TbButton).

I will update as I find the answer or if someone can help that would appreciated. Thanks!
0